# .htaccess simple rewrite to remove file extension not working - gives error 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, raspberry-pi, clean-urls

I'm coding on my new RaspberryPi. I tried to use .htaccess to remove the .php from a file called 'greet'.

I installed apache2: "**sudo apt-get install apache2**

Enabled the rewrite module using: "**sudo a2enmod rewrite**"

I have also changed the permission to override standard website configs.

I know my rewrite module is working, because I tried the following it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^greet.html$ greet.php
```

which successfully redirects 192.168.0.123/greet.html to 192.168.0.123/greet.php.

However the following code to remove the .php file extension doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When I type http://192.168.0.123/greet into my browser I don't get the greet.php file. Instead I end up on a ***404 Not Found*** page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try your rule this way.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. Panama Jack. I have tried it. Still getting the same error. - Not found when I access http://192.168.0.123/greet

Comment: Try and clear your browser cache and try it again with these rules.

Comment: I tried clearing my browser cache. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using multiviews to handle this? If you don't have a lot of complicated rewrite rules, you could just have mod_negotiation handle these extensions for you. Just need to turn it on

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Comment: I am sorry. I tried. It didn't work.

Options +Multiviews  RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: @user2646237 you don't need that rewrite rule, multiviews takes care of that for you

Comment: I see. I am sorry. I tried it and still didn't resolve the problem!